# Knockout not populating DateTime? when initial is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to bind my view model to my view. Multiple properties in my view model are nullable, such as `DateTime?`s. Here's an example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, the property `CreationDate` is a nullable `DateTime`.

I'm binding the property with a custom datepicker binder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        try {
            var jsonDate = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var value = parseJsonDateString(jsonDate);
            var strDate = value.getMonth() + 1 + "/"
                            + value.getDate() + "/"
                            + value.getFullYear();
            element.setAttribute('value', strDate);
        }
        catch (exc) {
        }
        $(element).change(function () {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            value(element.getAttribute('value'));
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var val = valueAccessor();
        val(element.getAttribute('value'));
    }
};

var jsonDateRE = /^\/Date\((-?\d+)(\+|-)?(\d+)?\)\/$/;
var parseJsonDateString = function (value) {
    var arr = value && jsonDateRE.exec(value);
    if (arr) {
        return new Date(parseInt(arr[1]));
    }
    return value;
};
```

This enables me to bind my property in the view like so:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="datepicker: CreationDate" />
```

**Problem**

Here's the problem. Sometimes this property is already null when it enters the view. A JSON example could look like this:

```
{
  "Id": 2004,
  "Name": "Test",
  "CreationDate": null
}
```

If this is the case, and I change this value to some random value from the datepicker, and send an ajax POST to my controller, I can see that models `CreationDate` still is equal to `null`.

So if the `DateTime` is null as the model enters the view, how do I populate the models property?

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution on my own**

I managed to solve my issue by simply changing my binding to the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            var value = $(element).val();
            // if the input field is empty, the value is falsy and therefore the observable should be = null
            if(!value){
                observable(null);
            } else {
                var date = new Date(value);
                observable(date);
            }
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    //update the control when the view model changes
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        //if the value received is null, we should display nothing in the input field
        if (value === null) {
            $(element).val(null);
        } else {
            //we need to manipulate the data to show something user friendly to the user
            var date = parseJsonDateString(value);
            var strDate = date.getMonth() + 1 + "/"
                                        + date.getDate() + "/"
                                        + date.getFullYear();
            $(element).val(strDate);
        }
    }
};
```

So basically if the value I'm getting in the `update` function, simply set `$(element).val(null)`. This way, nullable properties are handled correctly.